# Converting mysql tables from latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, latin1, mysql-error-1062

I'm trying to convert some mysql tables from latin1 to utf8. I'm using the following command, which seems to mostly work.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

However, on one table I get an error about a duplicate key entry. This is caused by a unique index on a "name" field. It seems when converting to utf8, any "special" characters are indexed as their straight english equivalent. For example, there is already a record with a name field value of "Dru". When converting to utf8, a record with "Drü" is considered a duplicate. The same with "Patrick" and "Påtrìçk".

Here is how to reproduce the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (   `name` char(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES ('Drü'),('Dru'),('Patrick'),('Påtrìçk');

ALTER TABLE example convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Dru' for key 1
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason why the strings `'Drü'` and `'Dru'` evaluate as the same is that in the `utf8_general_ci` collation, they count as "the same". The purpose of a *collation* for a character set is to provide a set of rules as to when strings are the same, when one sorts before the other, and so on.

If you want a different set of comparison rules, you need to choose a different collation. You can see the available collations for the `utf8` character set by issuing `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8%'`. There are a bunch of collations intended for text that is mostly in a specific language; there is also the `utf8_bin` collation which compares all strings as binary strings (i.e. compares them as sequences of 0s and 1s).

Answer (score 3):

`UTF8_GENERAL_CI` is accent insensitive.

Use `UTF8_BIN` or a language-specific collation.